# EF querying db context performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have `Student` class. `Student` class has `4 public methods.` Two of them need to query the same entity from DB and two of them not.

I have two approaches to that.

**Approach 1** will have `2 DB` calls.

**Approach 2** will have `4 DB` calls (every time class instantiated) unless EF do some magic and read out from local context if present.

Is there any better way?

**Approach 1**

```
public class Student
{

    public Method1()
    {

    }

    public Method2()
    {

    }

    public Method3()
    {
        List<Student> result = context.students.toList();
    }

    public Method3()
    {
        List<Student> result = context.students.toList();
    }

}
```

**Approach 2**

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        List<Student> result = context.students.toList();
    }

    public Method1()
    {

    }

    public Method2()
    {

    }

    public Method3()
    {
    }

    public Method3()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: it all depends on what you're trying to achieve. Obviously, if the data does not change you do not have to load it every time. It also depends on what your environment is. What kind of an application is this?

Comment: considering performance, I would never use `.ToList()` on your entire database. I would search for certain objects using `.Where()` and use `.ToList()` on that list afterwards.